# What methods are called when opening app from push notification

Tags: android

I'm trying to figure out what methods are called when my app is opened by tapping on a push-notification banner.  The app appears to re-launch?

Comment: pendingintent is triggered, configured with activity/service/broadcast

Answer (score 0):

you can use pending Intent, like this:

```
    val intent = Intent(this@MyFirebaseMessagingService, NextActivity::class.java)
    val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 101, intent,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
```

and set `pendingIntent` to your `notification.Builder`.